# non system disk or disk error when installing Lubuntu on an old HP laptop

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, lubuntu, disk

I have an old HP laptop that I wanted to put Lubuntu on (It had Win 7 on previously). I booted from my USB, installed Lubuntu but when I tried booting from laptops hard drive I got:

```
non system disk or disk error
```

error. Has anyone encountered anything similar and if yes do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and if that doesn't fix the problem, [edit] your question and provide the log.  If it does work, please leave a comment.

Comment: FYI:   Lubuntu and flavors of Ubuntu have shorter lives that the main Ubuntu.  Yes Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (*from 2014.April [yy.mm]*) is supported for 5 years, Lubuntu 14.04 LTS & other flavors only had 3 years of support (for desktop & all packages not found in 'main' (or from Ubuntu itself) - thus I'd suggest re-installation of a later release of Lubuntu that is fully-supported instead of using a release that only has some packages supported, others being EOL.

Answer (score 3):

Using fdsik I figured out that there was no bootable partition so I did this:

```
fdisk  /dev/sda
```

Command (m for help): m

```
Command action
a   toggle a bootable flag
b   edit bsd disklabel
c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
d   delete a partition
l   list known partition types
m   print this menu
n   add a new partition
o   create a new empty DOS partition table
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
s   create a new empty Sun disklabel
t   change a partition's system id
u   change display/entry units
v   verify the partition table
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)

Command (m for help): a
```

I only had one partition so it was automatically set to that one. After that everything worked fine.